# Slow access after many deletion in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a question. I have database in which one table is cleared and filled up with data again once a day. After many operations like this access to this table is much slower.

I cleared this table with command `DELETE FROM table_name` and then `COPY INTO table_name...` - I didn't use `VACCUM`. Now I have dropped table_name and create it again -> performance is again on high level.

Now instead of `DELETE FROM ...` I use `TRUNCATE table_name` and I'm wondering if it will  work better.

Maybe problem is with index (this one which is created during creating table)?

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.23.

Answer (score 3):

8.1 is old, unsupported, has tons of limitations in vacuum, and should be upgraded to a modern version as soon as practical. It isn't just an in-place upgrade, you must do a dump and reload and you **need to read the documentatation** - both the upgrade docs and the upgrade notes section of the release notes for the major versions 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2.

Using `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE` should indeed help. You should also `DROP` the index before loading the table and re-`CREATE` it afterwards. See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html).

In a vaguely modern version you should also do the `TRUNCATE` and `COPY` in the same transaction, as this allows PostgreSQL to perform several useful optimisations.

Comment: problem is thaht I have to do this on 8.1. Another problem is that when I'm trying to drop table_name_pkey index I've got error
`ERROR: cannot drop index info_pkey because constraint info_pkey on table info requires it HINT: You may drop constraint info_pkey on table info instead.`

Comment: @p_piorkowski Well, if load-time is a problem you have to drop any dependent foreign key constraints and re-create them too. You don't have to drop indexes, it can just be a little faster. As for "have to do it on 8.1" - find whoever says that and show them http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ . You'll have to upgrade eventually and it'll only get more painful the longer you wait.